# call a script python with php and return values

Tags: python, php

I would like to call a python script from a php page. The problem is that I need to send an argument to my script (an array) and my python needs to return an array to my php.
I send the right value to my python script but it returns an int for no apparent reason.

I tested my python script and it returns an array.

Do you know how I could do this?

```
$Alemme = explode(" ",$deleteUseless);
$output = $Alemme;
exec('python pythonFonctions.py', $output, $retval); 
$Splitmots = $retval;
```

Comment: Python's array is pretty much meaningless outside of the Python interpreter.

Comment: Why don't you simply implement an API? It's a standard and easy way to make services communicate together.

Comment: My python script performs a lemmatisation of each element of my array. I'm not sure how I can do this with an API.